# How to find the number in the middle

Tags: python, python-3.x

`n1`, `n2`, and `n3` are numbers. I want to return the number in the middle, e.g. if the numbers were 7, 2, 9, I would want to return 7. With the code I've currently written, it always returns `n3` no matter what. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

```
def mid3(n1, n2, n3):
    if n1 > (n2 or n3) and n1 < (n2 or n3):
        return n1
    elif n2 < (n1 or n3) and n2 > (n1 or n3):
        return n2
    else:
        return n3
```

Comment: Don't know python, but in most languages, we cannot use `x > (y or z)` like that.  It reads well in English, but not in programming language math.  We use expressions like this instead: `x > y || x > z` so the conjunctive (or) joins two relational expressions (>), not the other way around (a relational joining a conjunctive).

Answer (score 1):

In python, (unlike most languages), you are actually allowed to use a construct like: `n1 <= n2 <= n3` so your code could read:

```
if n1 <= n2 <= n3:
    return n2
elif n2 <= n1 <= n3:
```

etc. but you are going to have to type in all of the possibilities so it is much more pythonic to use a one liner:

```
return sorted([n1, n2, n3])[1]
```

This can be generalised to:

```
def mid(*items):
    """ Return the middle value from all of the parameters """
    return sorted(items)[len(items)//2]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Programming languages don't work that way.**

To understand why not, it's important to see that the sentence "N1 is greater than N2 or N3" is really a short-cut version of "N1 is greater than N2 and N1 is greater than N3". (Note that this is quite a complicated transformation - among others the AND turns into an OR, and it's a rather subtle problem to find out why exactly.)

Our brains are so used to this kind of shorthand that we don't even notice the difference. But compilers aren't - they are extremely literal, and therefore it's not (easily) possible to make a computer language that allows you to write with similar shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is efficient for calculating the median of 3 values:

```
max(min(n1, n2), min(max(n1, n2), n3))
```